# Paging a Gridview with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

So I have a List :-

```
static List<ListOfEmployees> employees = new List<ListOfEmployees> 
{ 
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "John Doe", Address = "123 Test Ave S, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-2345", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("2/23/2013")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Billy Rodney", Address = "551E 44th Ave, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-1234", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("1/2/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Arne Riise", Address = "99W Hwy21, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-4466", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("6/11/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Mike Duty", Address = "1450 Hilyard Lane, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-9987", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("11/21/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Nigel Poppet", Address = "771 Fox Run, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-6655", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("5/9/2013")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Shawn Dot", Address = "1220 Ferry St, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-3345", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("8/15/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Man Child", Address = "PO Box #221, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-9987", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("12/23/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Mike Duty", Address = "1450 Hilyard Lane, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-9987", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("11/21/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Nigel Poppet", Address = "771 Fox Run, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-6655", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("5/9/2013")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Shawn Dot", Address = "1220 Ferry St, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-3345", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("8/15/2014")},
   new ListOfEmployees {Name = "Man Child", Address = "PO Box #221, Eugene, OR", Phone = "541-123-9987", DateOfHire = Convert.ToDateTime("12/23/2014")}
};
```

It belongs to the ListOfEmployee class.

I am learning linq and have implemented a simple linq query:-

```
private IEnumerable<ListOfEmployees> returnEmployees(DateTime userInputLimit, int rowIndex)
{
    var Employees =
    from e in employees
    where e.DateOfHire < userInputLimit
    select e;

    createEmployeesDataTable(Employees);

    // Paginate //
    Employees = Employees.Take(11).Skip(rowIndex);

    return Employees.ToList();
}
```

The returned results get bound to my aspx Gridview:-

```
private void submitQuery(int rowIndex)
{
    DateTime userInputLimit = Convert.ToDateTime(txtboxHireDate.Text);
    var Employees = returnEmployees(userInputLimit, rowIndex);
    gvw_Linq_Results.DataSource = Employees;

    gvw_Linq_Results.DataBind();
}
```

Once bound, I am implementing Paging for the Gridview:-

```
protected void gvw_Linq_Results_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    int pageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvw_Linq_Results.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    submitQuery(pageIndex*gvw_Linq_Results.PageSize);
}
```

The issue is that, lets say I have 11 employees, my gridview maxPageSize = 5. Right away I get 3 page indexes displayed on my UI. Now when I click the 2nd page, my UI display shows results of the 2nd page correctly, but in the display, the first page is lost and the 2nd page gets displayed as the 1st page and the 3rd page gets displayed as the 2ndpage.

Alternatively if I click on the 3rd page right away, then both my 1st and 2nd pages are lost from the UI display, and I only get 1 gridview page with 1 row (since 11records - 2pages*5records/page).

I am not familiar with linq and skip/take techniques and wondering if anyone can help me figure this issue out.

Comment: I have seen people on the Net work with IQueryable and use the same skip/take methodology... Does using IEnumerable have anything to do with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution that worked for me is:-

```
    // Paginate //
    Employees = Employees.Take(11).Skip(0);
```

Changing my skip to go back to the 0th rowIndex. I guess my understanding previously was that skip is actually what took care of the pagination...I am still unsure about it, but this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is arising because you are not storing the current index. Your solution depends upon the scenarios you are working in.

- **Web based environment :** I would ask you to store the current page index in a session state variable or pass it as a query parameter. In your code behind then you can send the result by retrieving the value.
- **Forms or Store apps :** Better make a global variable in the code behind which stores your result from the LINQ query. Storing the value in a global variable would ensure that you don't need to iterate over again and again. You can then take sub-sections of the whole result according to the query made by the user.

Comment: actually my current index is stored, I can put breakpoints and see it change correctly. I don't need session state. Aspx Gridview control IndexChanging event parameter takes care of it. Further if index didn't actually get stored, then the pagination part of my gridview wouldn't work at all.